# Can I call a html div element from an angularjs function?

Tags: html, angularjs

I know the question is kind of dumb, but it's necessary for me. We can call angular function from html div tag using ng-click or ng-change. My question is if I can do the reverse. Say I want to repeat a particular div element & I can't use ng-repeat in this case. I want to repeat that using an angular function. Is it possible? Please help! I am using laravel 5.1 as backend.

```
<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <li class='role_li'>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-checked='1' name = 'rolelist[]' 
                                    ng-model = 'roleMenu.rolelist[{$row->title}]' 
                                    ng-change='myFunctionAdd({$role_id},{$row->title},{$row->menu_id})'
                                    ng-click='myFunctionR($key,{$row->title},{$row->menu_id})'
                                          id = '{$row->menu_id}'
                              ng-true-value='{$row->menu_id}' 
                              ng-false-value=''/>
                            &nbsp;<strong>{$row->route_alias_name}</strong></br></br>
  </li>
</div>
```

This is the div block that I want to repeat. This is for making a tree view of a list with parent id etc.

```
public function has_children($rows,$id) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if ($row->parent_menu_id == $id)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
public function build_menu($rows,$parent=0,$role_id)
{  
    $result = "<ul>";
    foreach ($rows as $key=> $row)
    {
        if ($row->parent_menu_id == $parent){

   //if(strpos($row->route_alias_name, 'list') !== false){
        $result.="<div class='col-sm-6'>";
        $result.= "<li class='role_li'>";


        $result.=" <input type='checkbox' ng-checked='1' name = 'rolelist[]' 
                                    ng-model = 'roleMenu.rolelist[{$row->title}]' 
                                    ng-change='myFunctionAdd({$role_id},{$row->title},{$row->menu_id})'
                                    ng-click='myFunctionR($key,{$row->title},{$row->menu_id})'
                                          id = '{$row->menu_id}'
                              ng-true-value='{$row->menu_id}' 
                              ng-false-value=''/>
                            &nbsp;<strong>{$row->route_alias_name}</strong></br></br>";
        if(strpos($row->route_alias_name, '_menu')){
          $result.="<label>(Menu)</label>";  
        }
        if(strpos($row->route_alias_name, '_submenu')){
          $result.="<label>(Sub Menu)</label>";  
        }
        if(strpos($row->route_alias_name, 'view')){
          $result.="<label>(View)</label>";  
        }
        if(strpos($row->route_alias_name, 'action')){
          $result.="<label>(Action)</label>";  
        }                        
        $result.="</div>";
        //}
        if ($this->has_children($rows,$row->menu_id))

        $result.= $this->build_menu($rows,$row->menu_id,$role_id);

        $result.= "</li>";

     }
    }

    $result.= "</ul>";

    return $result;
}
```

This are the two functions in laravel controller, this was done for inserting the tree view in my html. But directives like ng-repeat, ng-checked they don't work. So the main purpose is to convert this to angular way, so that i can use directives.

[This is the generated treeview. But the checkboxes don't work. ng-click, ng-checked directives are not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcvFr.png)

Comment: Call mean create? maybe use angular element?
 very much same as jquery https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking and why `ng-repeat` won't work. Please add examples to illustrate your problem.

Comment: are you facing any issue while using ng-repeat?

Comment: Sorry I didn't state it clearly. The fact is not that I can't use, it is rather I don't want to in this case. I am trying to make a tree-view of a list of items. I want to do that in my view page phuzi.

Comment: @SouravBhowmik sounds like a combination of a `ng-repeat` and a `treeItem` directive which gets called recursively would solve that nicely. Perhaps adding a bit of code showing what you have tried and where you're  getting stuck would help us to help you :)

Comment: @phuzi I have updated my question, please revise it. :) & thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS and you have requirement of repeating DOM element, you should use `ng-repeat` but I think you want some other way to do it which should be from AngularJS. So simple solution to do this would be using `VanilaJS` i.e pure Javascript

Use:

`var el = document.getElementById()`

and then appen new element(repeating) to that HTML DOM

`el.append("<div>Repeating element goes here<div>")`

But please understand this is not ideal way when you are using `AngularJS` like framework, Try to fulfil your requirement using framework feature like `ng-repeat` itself as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sidgujrathi. Unfortunately I will have to stick with angularJS here.

Comment: Great!! Glad you figured it out. Do accept this answer and up vote to support and build better developer community. Thank you @SouravBhowmik